# lm() coefficients -> vector with commas

Tags: multiple-regression, regression-coefficients

Question:
I want to put the coefficients from a call to lm() into a vector with commas such as 
vec=c(325.4361167,0.0675257,2.5519813,3.8001944,-22.9494678,2.4174843 )
How to do?

My Code

```
fit <- lm(y~x1+x2+x3+x4+x5)
fit
fit$coefficients
class(fit$coefficients)
vec <- c(fit$coefficients)
vec
coeffs <- coefficients(fit) does the same.
```

Output:

```
> fit
Call:
lm(formula = y ~ x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 + x5)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)           x1           x2           x3           x4           x5  
  325.43612      0.06753      2.55198      3.80019    -22.94947      2.41748  

> fit$coefficients
(Intercept)          x1          x2          x3          x4          x5 
325.4361167   0.0675257   2.5519813   3.8001944 -22.9494678   2.4174843

> class(fit$coefficients)
[1] "numeric"

> vec <- c(fit$coefficients)
> vec
(Intercept)          x1          x2          x3          x4          x5 
325.4361167   0.0675257   2.5519813   3.8001944 -22.9494678   2.4174843 

> coeffs <- coefficients(fit)
> coeffs
(Intercept)          x1          x2          x3          x4          x5 
325.4361167   0.0675257   2.5519813   3.8001944 -22.9494678   2.4174843 
>
```

My Data

```
   id     y     x1    x2    x3    x4    x5
1   1 271.8 783.35 33.53 40.55 16.66 13.20
2   2 264.0 748.45 36.50 36.19 16.46 14.11
3   3 238.8 684.45 34.66 37.31 17.66 15.68
4   4 230.7 827.80 33.13 32.52 17.50 10.53
5   5 251.6 860.45 35.75 33.71 16.40 11.00
6   6 257.9 875.15 34.46 34.14 16.28 11.31
7   7 263.9 909.45 34.60 34.85 16.06 11.96
8   8 266.5 905.55 35.38 35.89 15.93 12.58
9   9 229.1 756.00 35.85 33.53 16.60 10.66
10 10 239.3 769.35 35.68 33.79 16.41 10.85
```

Thank you.
MM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `vec` object is already vector "with commas" such as used when making one with `c()`. It is  a named numeric vector, so it looks a little different. If you want to get rid of the names, you can do `unname(vec)`. If you want to make one string with them separated by commas, you can do `paste(vec, collapse = ", ")`.

Comment: I needed to prepare for a run of paretoChart after running lm.beta to get standardized coefficients. I store the results in fit_std.  Then stdBetaCoeff <- abs(coefficients(fit_std))
followed by pareto.chart(stdBetaCoeff). I still need to work on your post, however. I need to take the mystery out of vectors. Thanks. MM